# Getting installation error after trying to use npm install -g nemwan in command prompt. Unable to see Newman version code line

Tags: installation, package, uuid, newman

I have Installed node js  and set path in Env. variable. After that I am trying to installing newman from below mentioned command:

npm install -g newman

but I am getting below error.

```
 npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
    npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
changed 111 packages, and audited 112 packages in 5s

5 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

[image]

[image]

What process should I follow to resolve this issue?
I have used latest version of node.js.

Answer (score -1):

These are not errors, it's just warnings related to the dependencies used in newman. Is this blocking you from doing anything?